# Can someone explain why my modal isn't working. I think it has to do with my populateEpisodes function because the getEpisodes array is returned fine

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Top section is my HTML, bottom is my Javascript. This is my first time using stackoverflow, so I may have formatted the code wrong on here. My modal won't connect to the 'get episodes' button for some reason. I think it has something to do with my populateEpisodes function because getEpisodes console.logs the array of episodes object, so I have the array but I can't figure out why my modal won't work.

```js
const missingPhotoURL = "URL stack wouldn't let me post";

async function searchShows(query) {
  let showRequest = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${query}`);
  let showArray = [];

  for(let show of showRequest.data){
    let showObj = {
      id: show.show.id,
      name: show.show.name,
      summary: show.show.summary,
      image: show.show.image ? show.show.image.medium : missingPhotoURL
    };

    showArray.push(showObj)
  }
  console.log(showRequest);
  console.log(showArray);
  return showArray; //returns array of show objects
  }

function populateShows(shows) {
  const $showsList = $("#shows-list");
  $showsList.empty();

  for (let show of shows) {
    let $show = $(
      `<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 Show" data-show-id="${show.id}">
         <div class="card" data-show-id="${show.id}">
           <div class="card-body" id = "showCard">
             <img class="card-img-top" src=${show.image}>
             <h5 class="card-title">${show.name}</h5>
             <p class="card-text">${show.summary}</p>
             <button class="btn btn-outline-primary get-episodes" id="episodeButton" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#episodeModal">Show Episodes</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      `
    );
    
    $showsList.append($show);
  }
}

$("#search-form").on("submit", async function handleSearch (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  let query = $("#search-query").val();
  if (!query) return;

  $("#episodes-area").hide();

  let shows = await searchShows(query);

  populateShows(shows);
});

async function getEpisodes(id) {
  let episodesRequest = await axios.get(
    `http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}/episodes`
  );
  console.log(episodesRequest);
  let episodeArray = [];

  for(let episode of episodesRequest.data){
    let episodeObj = {
      id: episode.id,
      name: episode.name,
      season: episode.season,
      number: episode.number,
    };
    episodeArray.push(episodeObj);
  }
  console.log(episodeArray);
  return episodeArray;
}

async function populateEpisodes(episodes){
  const $episodesModalBody = $('.modalBody')
  //$episodesModalBody.empty();

  for(let episode of episodes){
    let $episodeBody = $(
      `<p> ${episode.name} (Season:${episode.season} Episode:${episode.number})</p>`
    );

    $episodesModalBody.append($episodeBody);
  }
}

$('#shows-list').on('click', '.get-episodes', async function episodeClick(e){
  let showID = $(e.target).closest('.Show').data('show-id');
  let episodes = await getEpisodes(showID);
  populateEpisodes(episodes);
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TV Maze</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>TV Maze</h1>

    <form class="form-inline" id="search-form">
      <input class="form-control" id="search-query" placeholder = 'Show Name'>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go!</button>
    </form>

    <div class="row mt-3" id="shows-list">
      <div class = 'modal fade' id = 'episodeModal' tabindex = '-1'>
        <div class = 'modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable' >
          <div class = 'modal-content'>
            <div class = 'modal-header'>
              <h5>Episode List:</h5>
            </div>

            <div class = 'modal-body'>

            </div>

            <div class = 'modal-footer'>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="http://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="tvmaze.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think if you say about what should happens in which condition we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `div` to populate inside of the modal body, and add `.modal('show')`, so the actual modal window can be shown.

```js
const missingPhotoURL = "URL stack wouldn't let me post";

async function searchShows(query) {
  let showRequest = await axios.get(`http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=${query}`);
  let showArray = [];

  for(let show of showRequest.data){
    let showObj = {
      id: show.show.id,
      name: show.show.name,
      summary: show.show.summary,
      image: show.show.image ? show.show.image.medium : missingPhotoURL
    };

    showArray.push(showObj)
  }
  console.log(showRequest);
  console.log(showArray);
  return showArray; //returns array of show objects
  }

function populateShows(shows) {
  const $showsList = $("#shows-list");
  $showsList.empty();

  for (let show of shows) {
    let $show = $(
      `<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 Show" data-show-id="${show.id}">
         <div class="card" data-show-id="${show.id}">
           <div class="card-body" id = "showCard">
             <img class="card-img-top" src=${show.image}>
             <h5 class="card-title">${show.name}</h5>
             <p class="card-text">${show.summary}</p>
             <button class="btn btn-outline-primary get-episodes" id="episodeButton" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#episodeModal">Show Episodes</button>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
      `
    );
    
    $showsList.append($show);
    $('#episodeModal').modal('show');
  }
}

$("#search-form").on("submit", async function handleSearch (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  let query = $("#search-query").val();
  if (!query) return;

  $("#episodes-area").hide();

  let shows = await searchShows(query);

  populateShows(shows);
});

async function getEpisodes(id) {
  let episodesRequest = await axios.get(
    `http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/${id}/episodes`
  );
  console.log(episodesRequest);
  let episodeArray = [];

  for(let episode of episodesRequest.data){
    let episodeObj = {
      id: episode.id,
      name: episode.name,
      season: episode.season,
      number: episode.number,
    };
    episodeArray.push(episodeObj);
  }
  console.log(episodeArray);
  return episodeArray;
}

async function populateEpisodes(episodes){
  const $episodesModalBody = $('.modalBody')
  //$episodesModalBody.empty();

  for(let episode of episodes){
    let $episodeBody = $(
      `<p> ${episode.name} (Season:${episode.season} Episode:${episode.number})</p>`
    );

    $episodesModalBody.append($episodeBody);
  }
}

$('#shows-list').on('click', '.get-episodes', async function episodeClick(e){
  let showID = $(e.target).closest('.Show').data('show-id');
  let episodes = await getEpisodes(showID);
  populateEpisodes(episodes);
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TV Maze</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>TV Maze</h1>

    <form class="form-inline" id="search-form">
      <input class="form-control" id="search-query" placeholder = 'Show Name'>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Go!</button>
    </form>

    <div class="row mt-3" >
      <div class = 'modal fade' id = 'episodeModal' tabindex = '-1'>
        <div class = 'modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable' >
          <div class = 'modal-content'>
            <div class = 'modal-header'>
              <h5>Episode List:</h5>
            </div>

            <div class = 'modal-body'>
              <div id="shows-list"></div>
            </div>

            <div class = 'modal-footer'>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
    <!--script src="tvmaze.js"></script-->

  </body>
</html>
```